# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm unable to load the car package in R. I tried reinstalling using

```
install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE)
```

both from R and RStudio. I tried installing `quantreg` as advised in another post and then installing it again. Installation appears to be successful, but simply can't load the program.

Here's the complete error:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>         there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’
>       In addition: Warning message: package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.2.3
>       Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’

Comment: You should upgrade R first. Then run `update.package(checkBuilt = TRUE)`. Finally, try again `install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)`. If it doesn't work, try to install package `pbkrtest` first.

Comment: should be `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Comment: When I encounter this I just install the packages that it says aren't installed and get on with my day.

Answer (score 9):

This was just bumped to the homepage by Community. I can't take credit for the answer, but to give it a real non-comment answer:

> You should upgrade R first. Then run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`. Finally, try again `install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE)`. If it doesn't work, try to install package pbkrtest first. - user3710546

Given that the current version of R at the time the question was posted was 3.2.3, I think that was a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error. (I am using R 3.2.2) Please perform the following steps in sequence (after that try to activate installed caret package):

```
install.packages("lme4", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/",type = "binary", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("nlme", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/",type = "binary", dependencies=TRUE)
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pbkrtest/pbkrtest_0.4-4.tar.gz" 
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

No need to upgrade R. I am still using R 3.2.2. I performed these steps and it worked for me.