# Loading the readr Package

Tags: r

When I try to load `readr` using the `library()` function, I get the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘readr’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’
```

I am relatively new to R.  So I am not sure how to interpret this error message.  Can you please show me how I can successfully load `readr`?

Thanks

Comment: try installing `Rcpp` first: `install.packages("Rcpp")`

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082143/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-car?rq=1

Comment: I ran "install.packages("Rcpp"), then re-installed readr, and it still didn't load the package.  I kept getting the same error message.

Comment: try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501507/lib-unspecified-error-in-loadnamespace

Comment: i got this warning: Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\gespe\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\file2e5460d87c3f\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\gespe\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\Rcpp’

Comment: hm, try to remove both folders, than rerun the installation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem is so frecuently. You should install R 3.3.2 (last version)

https://cran.r-project.org/

And restart your computer. It is not a problem of packages.

Comment: I just did that.  Thanks.  Now how do i integrate the new version in RStudio?  I have both the old and the new versions on my desktop.

Comment: First, you have to restart your Pc. Second, the integration beetween Old and new version of R is not a problem.

Comment: I restarted the computer and I was able to install and load readr.  Thanks!