# Error when trying to load car package in R studio cloud

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

I'm quite new to R so I don't understand what this error message is telling me.  When I try to load the car package I get this message :

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,.libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):there is no package called ‘openxlsx’

I'm working on the R studio cloud on a Chromebook. I believe the version is 3.6.0.

I've also tried this code but with no avail :
`install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082143/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-car possible duplicate

Comment: While I don't understand why access the `car` package is complaining about `openxlsx`, it seems that something the code is otherwise depending on it. Similar to @T.G.'s suggestion, have you attempted to resolve the actual error message about `openxlsx`?

Comment: This is a bit strange. I tried installing `openxlsx` package last night but it wouldn't install. However, I just tried this morning and it installed. Now the `car` package is working also. Thank you both @T.G.